# Shell: ls and xargs. xargs Prints a single line while expecting there to be a line per file

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I have the following directory:

```
> tree
.
├── a.txt
└── b.txt

> ls
a.txt   b.txt
```

When I run command `ls | xargs echo` I get the following:

```
> ls | xargs echo
a.txt b.txt
```

While I would have expected result to look something along the lines of

```
> ls | xargs echo
a.txt 
b.txt
```

Given that I am expecting `xargs` to process each file separately and `echo` to print each input on its own separate line.

Why the difference of expected vs actual?

---

Edit1:

As suggested I have tried:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec echo {} \;
```

Which does work as expected and I presume allows other command to be subbed in for echo with `-exec`.

However, trying the other suggestions to try to get xargs working still does not work (prints the output on the same line).

Example:

```
printf "%s\n" * | xargs
a.txt b.txt
```

```
> find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | xargs echo
./b.txt ./a.txt
```

Comment: `xargs` will by default put as many arguments into the command line of the program it runs as the host OS allows. Use `printf "%s\n" *` if you want one per line.

Comment: Also see [Why you shouldn't try to parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2):

Use `find`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
# or:
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec echo {} \;
```

If you *really* must parse the output of `ls` (**not** the recommended practice, see comments), use `xargs -n1`:

```
ls | xargs -n1 echo
```